# Publish messages to Pubsub topic in Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, google-iam

What is the recommended way to publish messages to a Pub/Sub topic in Dataflow.
I have worked with client APIs but do not think it is the best way to handle this in Dataflow.

```java
PublishResponse response = client.projects().topics()
                        .publish(fullTopicName, publishRequest)
                        .execute();
```

Comment: I am publishing the message from App Engine.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to publish messages to a PubSub topic from a Dataflow job is to use the `PubsubIO` class. Example:

```java
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();

// do some transforms

p.apply("publish message", PubsubIO.write().to("pubsub/topic"));
```

Reference: [PubsubIO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.html)

Comment: Could you please let me know the best way to publish large data(GBs) from AppEngine.

Comment: @Radhika, so is Dataflow involved at all? The best way to publish messages from App Engine (flexible environment) is to use one of the supported clients. Reference: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages.